# Авторизация на Django

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь сделать авторизацию. Регистрация через форму у меня уже есть. Когда зарегистрировались, автомотически переход на авторизцию. Мне необходимо выводить сообщение, если пользователь не найден, а если найдет, по кнопке переход на главную страницу. У меня не сообщение не выходит ни на главную не переходит. В чем может быть дело. Делала по шаблону

views.py

```html
# from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import auth
from .forms import AnketaForm
from .forms import RegistrationForm
# Это наша форма, которую мы определим в forms.py
# from .forms import AuthenticationForm
# Это наша форма, которую мы определим в forms.py
# from .forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import Personal
# Это наша форма, которую мы определим в forms.py
from .forms import AuthenticationForm


    # Create your views here.
def index(request):
    msg ='Заполните все поля данных'
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AnketaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            anketa = form.save(commit=False)
            anketa.save()
            msg = 'Ваши данные добавлены!'
            return render(request, 'logistic/index.html', {'form': form, 'message': msg,})
    else:
        form = AnketaForm()
    return render(request, 'logistic/index.html', {'form': form, 'message': msg,})


    
def about_company(request):
    return render(request, 'logistic/about_company.html')

def contacts(request):
    return render(request, 'logistic/contacts.html')

def questions_reviews(request):
    return render(request, 'logistic/questions-reviews.html')

def vacancies(request):
    return render(request, 'logistic/vacancies.html')

def services(request):
    return render(request, 'logistic/services.html')

def contacts_worker(request):
    return render(request, 'logistic/contacts_worker.html')





def regist(request):
    msg ='Заполните все поля данных'
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           Personal = form.save(commit=False)
           Personal.save()
           msg = 'Ваши данные добавлены!'
           return redirect('authoriz')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'logistic/index-registration.html', {'form': form, 'message': msg,})




  


def authoriz(request):
    error = ''
    if request.POST:
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.POST.get("username")
            pas = request.POST.get("password")
            users = auth.authenticate(username=user, password=pas)
            print(user)
            print(pas)
            if users is not None:
                auth.login(request, users)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                error = 'Такого пользователя не существует!'
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'logistic/index-authorization.html', {'form': form, 'error': error,})
```

urls.py

```html
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about_company', views.about_company, name='about_company'),
    path('contacts', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
    path('questions_reviews', views.questions_reviews, name='questions_reviews'),
    path('vacancies', views.vacancies, name='vacancies'),
    path('services', views.services, name='services'),
    path('contacts_worker', views.contacts_worker, name='contacts_worker'),
    
    path('a/', views.authoriz, name='authoriz'),
    path('r/', views.regist, name='regist'),
    # path('authentication', views.authentication, name='authentication'),
    # path('new_anketa/', views.new_anketa, name='new_anketa'),




]
```

forms.py

```html
from .models import Anketa
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, DateInput
from .models import Personal
from django import forms

class AnketaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Anketa
        fields = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6', 'q7', 'q8', 'q9']

        widgets = {
            "q1": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_1',

            }),
            "q2": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_2',

            }),
            "q3": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_3',

            }),
            "q4": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_4',

            }),
            "q5": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_5',

            }),
            "q6": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_6',

            }),
            "q7": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_7',

            }),
            "q8": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_8',

            }),
            "q9": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'window_question_9',

            }),
        }




class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personal
        fields = ['fio', 'date', 'username', 'password']

        widgets = {
            "fio": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'fio_input',

            }),
            "date": DateInput(attrs={
                'id': 'date_input',
                'type': 'date',

            }),
            "username": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'login_input',

            }),
            "password": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'password_input',
                'type': 'password',

            }),
           
            
        }



class AuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personal
        fields = ['username', 'password']

        widgets = {
            "username": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'login_input_autho',

            }),
            "password": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'password_input_autho',
                'type': 'password',

            })
           
            
        }
```

index-authorization.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Авторизация{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'logistic/css/registration and authorization.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <div class = "body">
        <img src = "{% static 'logistic/image/1900/1900-background.png' %}"/>
    </div>
    <form>
    <div class = "window_registration_autho">

        <div id = "header_registration_autho">Авторизация</div>
        <div id = "car_autho"><img src = "{% static 'logistic/image/background_car_autho.png' %}"/></div>
    
        <form action= "" method="POST">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <div class = "window_input_autho">

                    <div id = "login_autho">Логин</div>

                    <div id = "password_autho">Пароль</div>

            </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button-registration_autho">Войти!</input>
        {% csrf_token %}

    </form>
    <div class = "msg_autho">
        {{error}}
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в шаблоне забыли адрес указать:

```
<form action= "{% url 'authoriz' %}" method="POST">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div class = "window_input_autho">

                <div id = "login_autho">Логин</div>

                <div id = "password_autho">Пароль</div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Все равно не работает. Я регистрируюсь, потом автоматически перехожу на авторизацию. Ввожу неправильный логин и пароль, нажимаю кнопку и ничего. Ни сообщения. А при вводе правильного логина и пароля никакого перехода нет

Comment: Как будто он и не видит даже эти поля. А сверху появляется http://127.0.0.1:8000/a/?username=12345&password=12345&csrfmiddlewaretoken=a7YwtYjkT35Qem58ZyMV1gdFYOZ1V1R6kwxdiA6kURrvADJTWWPbNXXiKgbj9x32

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
if form.is_valid():
        user = request.POST['username']
        pas = request.POST['password']
```

И проверьте на всякий случай ошибки формы:

```
print(form.errors)
```

Comment: Также у вас в шаблоне лишний тэг <form>